# How do I serialize one to many object to ASP .NET MVC controller from JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a View Model, say `Class1`, which is bound to my view. `Class1` has `Model1` which is another class object and `Model2` which is a list. I have it in my view the name element as

```
Class1.Model1.Property1 etc...
Class1.Model2[n].Property1 etc...
```

When I use JQuery `$('form').serialize()` I get the `Class1` base properties properly serialized but others come back as `null`.

Any help in this regard is much appreciated.

View information:Base class -

```
<div class='col-sm-6'>
    @Html.TextBox("RoleMasterModel.ApplicationName", Model.ApplicationName, new { @disabled = "disabled", @class = "form-control", @MaxLength = "500" })
</div>
```

Model1 rendering  -

```
<div class='col-sm-6'>
     @Html.Hidden("RoleMasterModel.RoleModel.RoleId", Model.RoleModel.RoleId)
     @Html.TextBox("RoleMasterModel.RoleModel.RoleName", Model.RoleModel.RoleName, new { @class = "form-control", @MaxLength = "500" })
</div>
```

Model2 rendring -

```
<span>
    <input type="checkbox" value="false" id="RoleMasterModel.ApplicationRolePermissionModels[@Html.Raw(counter)].CanView" @Html.Raw((rolePermission.CanView) ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "") /> View
    <input type="hidden" class="associatedhidden" name="RoleMasterModel.ApplicationRolePermissionModels[@Html.Raw(counter)].CanView" value="false" />
</span>
```

Comment: Depends on how you are rendering the input fields in your view. You should share the relevant code of your razor view, and may be your view model structure as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Model1 rendering as Html helpers

but model2 using normal html ..

make sure all elements should come  as html helpers ..

then all values you can receive in controllers.